# Migrate from Google to Firebase analytics Android - Multiple trackers

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

In my current application, I am using multiple trackers to report my events. However, while migrating to Firebase we found that we can configure only one application corresponding to a Mobile app. Previously I was using multiple trackers to report events to customer and marketing company accounts.

1. Is it possible to report events to multiple Firebase analytics accounts simultaneously?
2. I am planning to connect my existing Google analytics accounts to Firebase analytics account. Is it possible for me to route the events from Firebase analytics to multiple Google analytics account? May be using something like Google Tag manager?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to report multiple Firebase account simultaneously with Firebase Analytics.

You have few options to emulate multiple trackers in Google Analytics:

1. You can export the Firebase Analytics data to BigQuery and DataStudio and provide customized access to different parties. This approach gives you a lot of flexibility but its quite involved.
2. As you suggested you can use Google Tag Manager and send data to multiple Google Analytics accounts. This approach is simpler but it has some limitations. First, you will not get as detailed app reporting from Google Analytics account as you would from Firebase Analytics. Since the data is send independently to each account there might be discrepancies between the accounts. You will be uploading the data multiple times, once for each account, as every account will needs the data uploaded separately. This uses more mobile data and system resources on the device.

Comment: Thanks! I will try the second option mentioned. I tried creating a custom variable (matching the Firebase event name), trigger and tag to be pushed to Google analytics. But i am not able to see the events in my Google analytics console. I can see events in Firebase console. What could i be missing?